# Enlarge flash game through VB

Tags: vb.net, flash, magnification

I'm trying to use Visual Basic to enlarge or magnify a flash game. (Just trying to make it take up more of the screen without having to do something like change the computer's resolution.)

The only code I have is the one that loads the game from the website:

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         webFlash.Movie = "http://www.website.com/file.swf"
         webFlash.ScaleMode = 0
    End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use ctrl+wheel up or down in your browser, that should do it. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Tested in my VB application and FireFox. Thank you though.

Comment: Try Chrome if your problem is limited enough, saves you hours of searching for ways to fix this problem.